Python VCL MenuItem text disappears when assigning ImageIndex when have a style
Loaded a style from file, but when assigning ImageIndex to a MenuItem the text disappears, everything else seems fine.
Not sure if there is additional properties for the ImageList to make this work.
Code Extract:
        imgLst2 = ImageList(self)
        imgLst2.SetProps(Height = 16, Width = 16,
                         DrawingStyle = 'dsTransparent',
                         Masked = False,
                         ColorDepth = 'cd32bit')
        for f in icoFileList:
            icon = Icon(self)
            icon.LoadFromFile(f)
            imgLst2.AddIcon(icon)
        icon.Free()
        mainMenu.Images = imgLst2
        mnuItm1.ImageIndex = 0  #The 'Text' disappear on MenuItem

Tried with different vcf Styles and all do the same. Not sure if it is a setting somewhere that needs to be added.
Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

